# Update gridview inline with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm trying to update a record called 'note' in a gridview inline through LINQ with the code below. My issue is when I run it and attempt to execute the `updNote_RowUpdating`, my project crashes stating that `var queryDetails` contains no elements.

Inspecting the `oldValue` variable shows that its content is as follows:
"`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedKeyValueCollection`"

The database is composed of several clients who have several notes allocated to them, all this information is stored in one database.

My code is as follows:

#### ASP.NET:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" class=" table table-bordered table-striped" OnRowEditing="updNoteEdit_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="updNote_RowUpdating" EnableViewState="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
               <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField> 
                        <ItemTemplate> 
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteRec" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  CommandName="select" Text="&times;"  class="close" ForeColor="red" OnClick="btn_delete_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                          <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Note" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Note") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>                    
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

#### C#:

```
protected void updNote_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    tblBasic currentClient = new tblBasic();

    var oldValue = "" + e.OldValues.Values;
    var newValue = "" + e.NewValues.Values;

    var queryDetails = (from clients in entities.tblBasics
                            where clients.Note == oldValue
                            select new
                            {
                                clients.Note
                            }).First();

    foreach (var client in entities.tblBasics)
        {
            currentClient.Note = newValue;
        }
        entities.SaveChanges();

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        DataBind();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @GrantWinney <br/> Just one from the collection. I intended to filter only the note I need to change in the LINQ statement, and update that one. The `oldValue` being the note the user sees and intends to change, after all, there is only one string in the generated textbox.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var oldValue = "" + e.OldValues.Values;
```

You are essentially calling `ToString()` on the `e.OldValues.Values` collection, which always returns the class name of the collection instead of its contents, and explains why you see this:

> System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedKeyValueCollection

You need to either concatenate all the values from `e.OldValues.Values` into a single string (possibly with `string.Join()`, assuming you're trying to search on *all* notes, or you can select a single note from the `e.OldValues.Values` collection to search on.

---

So each "value" in your collection is just a string, and you want to select the first matching one.

Try using this LINQ to select the note you want:

```
var matchingNote = e.OldValues.Values.Cast<string>().Where(n => n == "note").First();
```

Comment: Sorry for the annoyance, but what is the syntax for selecting a single note from the `e.OldValues.Values` collection?

Comment: The contents are just a string of text of which it contains the notes of a single person (notes are unique to a certain client's ID). If two notes are the same, just the first one will do (to keep things simple for now).

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck, I'm getting the same 'Sequence contains no elements' error. Is there anything else I could try?